# Array in data method gets updated in one method but still empty in another method

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my app I am trying to update an array. First I get data from the database and add it to the array and in another method I want to use that array. But the array does not get updated.

If I use my array `exerciseList` in the DOM it has the data but in the `getExercises` funciton the length of the array is still 0. It like I run the method before the data is added to the array or something like that.

Any Idea why this is not working?

```
data: () => ({
    exerciseList: []

});

created() {
    this.getDataBaseCollection("Exercise", this.exerciseList); // array gets information here
}
mounted() {
    this.getExercises();
},

methods: {
    getDataBaseCollection: function (CollectionName, list) {
        db.collection(CollectionName).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                list.push(doc.data());
            });
        });

    },

    getExercises: function () {
        console.log(this.exerciseList.length);  // length is 0 ?? array seems empty
    }
 },
```

Comment: `getDataBaseCollection` takes some time to be completed (ie it is asynchronous) thus when `getExercises` is called first time on `mounted`, the previous method has not yet completed. it is completed shortly after and updated via the `.onSnapshot` callback

Comment: @NikosM. Thanks. That sounds true I think, but is there anyway to run all methods when this `getDataBaseCollection` is completed. This is a key method that it's result is requied in all stages of the app.

Comment: Sure there is, update state (rerender) by calling an `init` function at the end of `.onSnapshot` callback

Comment: While data are not yet loaded (ie `.onSnapshot` has not been called) show for example a loader that informs the user to wait

Comment: @NikosM. Thanks, but is it possible to show an example in code, I cant understand what you mean by the `init` funtion. I am not bothered with user notification as currently I want to make sure my code is running only after the arrays have the data.

Answer (score 1):

I think a key missing part may be updating the component's `exerciseList` variable , not the `list` argument. They are not the same variable. Objects are passed by reference but arrays are passed to functions by value only which makes `list` it's own variable independent from `excerciseList`. This is rough code that shows some ways to make sure `exerciseList` is updated and how to know when the values are all in the array.

```
// include exerciseListLoaded to flag when all data is ready
data: () => ({
    exerciseList: [],
    exerciseListLoaded: false
});

created() {
    this.getDataBaseCollection("Exercise"); // array gets information here
}
mounted() {
    // based on timing of the `onSnapshot` callback related to `mounted` being called, this may likely still result in 0
    console.log("Mounted");
    this.getExercises();
},

watch: {
    // watch for all data being ready
    exerciseListLoaded () {
       console.log("All Loaded");
       this.getExercises();
    }
},

methods: {
    // be sure to update the exerciseList on the component
    getDataBaseCollection: function (CollectionName) {
        // being careful about `this` since within `onSnapshot` I suspect it will change within that function
        const componentScope = this;
        db.collection(CollectionName).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                componentScope.exerciseList.push(doc.data());
                // could also still update `list` here as well if needed
            });
            // setting this allows the component to do something when data is all loaded via the `watch` config
            componentScope.exerciseListLoaded = true;
        });

    },

    getExercises: function () {
        console.log(this.exerciseList.length);  // length is 0 ?? array seems empty
    }
 },
```

Answer (score -1):

when you use `this` inside a function it refers to the function not the vue instance so you may use that may work with you:

```
getExercises() {
        console.log(this.exerciseList.length);  
    }
```